# Hide scrollbar, but still be able to scroll on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a problem hiding the scrollbar on my page but I still want to be able to scroll.

I know I can use

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
```

, but its obviously not working on Firefox or other non-webkit browsers.

Ive read a lot of threads explaining how can I accomplish this, but i just cant get it to work.

Can someone help me with this?

Website:  http://test.6f.sk/

Comment: Semi-related, IE and Edge do this with `-ms-overflow-style: none;`. So it really is only FF that's (AFAIK) unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}
```

or any other element where you want to disable scrollbars

Comment: thats working just like overflow: hidden;  it hides the scrollbar, but the scrolling function is not working

Comment: it seems that there is no equivalent for firefox. A hack would be to use a negative margin but the width of the scrollbars varies.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I know of is to just position the scrollbars out of view:

```css
.crop {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scroller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  /* Must be ≥ scrollbar width. Scrollbar width varies by
   * browser, OS, and config, so don't be precise, choose
   * something wider than any scrollbar.
   */
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <div class="scroller">
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
    11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also worth noting that `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` produces buggy behavior in Safari (current version 11.0.1) when used to hide a horizontal scrollbar on a page with an enabled Back button.